# When are scoped queries better than querying the entire document

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom

Let's say I have a lot of elements with a particular class `foo` on my page. 
All these elements are guaranteed to be within the element `ancestor`.

Which of these queries is going to be faster:

`$match = $(ancestor).find('.foo')` vs `$match = $('.foo')`

For a general query, I know that the first alternative is supposed to be faster, but does that still hold when I am querying purely based on a class?

Part of my confusion also stems from having read accounts of people recommending the first type (for a general query at least), but I also recently read that the browser's native implementation of

`ancestor.querySelectorAll('.foo')` is NOT faster than `document.querySelectorAll('.foo')` -- the reason for that apparently being that the former is implemented by calling the latter and then filtering out elements not belonging to `ancestor`.

EDIT

As someone has pointed out, I can test this myself. I do plan to do that. However, it'd be great if someone could explain *why* selection using `jQuery` is supposed to benefit from scoping while `querySelectorAll` is not (again, assuming all matching element are within a known ancestor, so scoping won't alter the results in any way)

Comment: Bottom line is, you'll never notice the difference.

Comment: What if you have `.foo` elements outside of `ancestor`?

Comment: And a question, is `ancestor` an ID or a more complicated selector, as that would make a difference me thinks.

Comment: Why not test it yourself?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, @adeneo: As the question says clearly, there are no `.foo` elements outside `ancestor`, and the `ancestor` is an `element`, not a selector etc.
@others: I plan to test it at some point, but it'll still not tell me the *why* part of it (see edited question)

Comment: for a long time jQuery didn't use querySelectorAll, still might not. If that's the case, the sorting through a fewer number of elements will be faster than sorting through more for obvious reasons.